# Couchbase times out after few seconds

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I have about 100-200k small documents which contain base64 encoded images (quite small images). I am trying to insert all these documents to the Couchbase and I keep getting this error after first 28k documents (about 185 Mb total size)

```
[Error: Client-Side timeout exceeded for operation. Inspect network conditions or increase the timeout] code: 23
```

Here is screenshot of Couchbase settings (I see only one strange thing here — free space is totally wrong, actually it is about 300GB of free space on my disk)

[image: scr]

My code is pretty simple and looks like this

```
 _.forOwn(data, function (data) {
    var item_id = "item::" + uid().toString();

    db.set(item_id, data, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('cb error', err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('cb success', result);
        }
    });
 });
```

I tried to alter documents and make them smaller or larger — it doesn't matter, after 28k database stops responding. It saves 28k in few seconds and then throws timeout. What should I do to fix this issue?

---

upd

I installed Couchbase 2.5 Enterprise and now free space is shown correctly. However I am still not able to pass through 28k limit. I am running Mac OS X 10.9.2. Maybe I should try to use Python or Java SDK for example?

[image: scr2]

---

Tried to install Couchbase on Ubuntu 14.04, now get the same error after 46k docs.

Here is screenshot of graphs (two peaks shows my two attempts to import files into Couchbase)
[image: scr3]

Comment: What OS are you running this on? The free space on the storage size looks like the problem to me, the value on my local instance shows the correct size of my disk.  What version of Couchbase are you running?  I'd be tempted to uninstall it and reinstall the latest version and see what happens.

Comment: @scalabilitysolved Please take a look at update in my post :) After installing latest version free space issue is gone, but I am still running into timeouts

Comment: Is this on your local computer?  Could you include how you instantiate the client? What version of libcouchbase do you have installed?

Comment: @scalabilitysolved Yes, this is my local machine, I just run Couchbase from Applications folder, and create client from nodejs via `var db = new couchbase.Connection({host: 'localhost:8091', bucket: 'default'});`. I have libcouchbase-2.3.1 installed.

Comment: This looks similar to your issues http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/couchnode-operation-callbacks-slow

I'm going to assume you are just throwing too much at your node, what does the disk drain queue look like?   Unfortunately I've never used node.js, I'd reach out to Brett who can probably help you -> https://twitter.com/Brett19x

Comment: @scalabilitysolved I attached screenshot of Couchbase sensors (now from Ubuntu in VirtualBox on same machine)

Comment: I deleted the bucket created a new one and was able to overcome this issue. Not saying this is a legitimate answer, but it worked for me.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

This issue was solved when I switched from nodejs sdk to python sdk.

Comment: I'm sorry but how is this a solution to the problem?

Comment: Maybe node.js sdk at that time had some critical issues. Python sdk was better supported.

Comment: I hope those issues have been resolved as I'm also having difficulty. Python is not an option for me though.

Comment: I hope these issues are solved too, but remembering my struggle back then, first thing I'd recommend to anyone who would like to use Couchbase is to use python SDK, since it has much better support :-) It's my personal opinion.

Comment: Not an option for most people/organizations.

Comment: @CoreyQuillen of course it is the best option for most people and organizations

Answer (score 5):

Switch to couchbase protocol and increase timeout.

Here's an example of connection to local couchbase from node.js:

```
callback = function(err)
{
  if (err)
    throw err;
}

var cluster = cluster = new couchbase.Cluster("couchbase://localhost/default");
var bucket = cluster.openBucket("default", callback);
bucket.operationTimeout = 60 * 1000; // 60 seconds operation timeout (LCB_CNTL_OP_TIMEOUT)
```

Please note that "localhost:8091" - is http protocol **only**.

Comment: Thanks for the protocol tips! This is the one i was looking for!